# questions about function object in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, functor, function-object

I have a question regarding the following piece of code.

```
template <typename T>
struct DisplayElementKeepCount
{
    int m_nCount;
    DisplayElementKeepCount () { m_nCount = 0; }
    void operator () (const T& element){++ m_nCount; cout<<element<<‘ ‘;}
};
```

when calling, it is written as:

```
DisplayElementKeepCount <int> mResult;
mResult = for_each ( vecIntegers.begin (), vecIntegers.end (), DisplayElementKeepCount <int> () );
```

I don't quite understand, because operator() needs a parameter "element", but it was not included when being called. why?

The example of IsMultiple actually gives a parameter when called. Why are these two different??

```
template <typename numberType>
struct IsMultiple
{
    numberType m_Divisor;
    IsMultiple (const numberType& divisor)
    {
        m_Divisor = divisor;
    }
    
    // The comparator of type: bool f(x)
    bool operator () (const numberType& element) const
    {
        // Check if the dividend is a multiple of the divisor
        return ((element % m_Divisor) == 0);
    }
};
...
vector <int>::iterator iElement;
iElement = find_if ( vecIntegers.begin (), vecIntegers.end (), 
IsMultiple <int> (4) );
```

Comment: Your second example is providing a parameter to the constructor of `IsMultiple`, not `operator()`. The parameter to `operator()` is passed to the functor inside the algorithm for each element in the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example `DisplayElementKeepCount` has a default constructor (which takes zero parameters) and you're using it.

```
for_each ( vecIntegers.begin (), vecIntegers.end (), DisplayElementKeepCount <int> () );
                                                                   //  Constructor ^^
```

If you were calling `operator()` it would look like the following.

```
DisplayElementKeepCount<int>()(5)
             // Constructor ^^
                           // ^^^ calling operator() on the unnamed instance
```

---

In your second example `IsMultiple` has a constructor which takes a single parameter.

```
find_if ( vecIntegers.begin (), vecIntegers.end (), IsMultiple <int> (4) );
                                                      // Constructor ^^^
```

Again, if you were calling `operator()` it would look like the following.

```
IsMultiple<int>(4)(2)
// Constructor ^^^
               // ^^^ calling operator() on the unnamed instance
```

Comment: I appreciate your explanation. But I still have a question here. According to your comment, operator() was not called, only constructor was called. Is it correct?